# Tension on wire holding open door, using moments about a hinge?

Tags: forces, statics

Using moments about the hinge, what is the tension in the wire holding the door open?

The wire is horizontal.  The door is 5m.  See diagram:

[image]

The door is at tan inv (3/4) : 36.9 deg to the horizontal.
Weight m of door is 24 kg and g is 10 ms^-2.

```
mg = 240N and acts from the midpoint of the door 2.5m vertically down
T tension acts from the end of the door at 5m
```

Perpendicular distance to hinge from T is 3m.
Perpendicular diatance from midpoint of door to hinge is 2.5m x cost 36.9deg = 2m
So :

```
T x 3metres = mg x 2.5metres cos 36.9
```

Solve for T and I get 160N... but that is not correct according to the answers.

Edit:  The door is 4m!  Not 5m.  Got the correct answer now.

Comment: I've just had a go at this and also got 160N. I've checked your working too and it looks good. What do the answers say the answer is?

Comment: Door is 4m not 5m.  The gap is 4m and the door fills that gap.

Comment: +1 Good solve! This revises my answer to 106N.